# how to fetch data and join two tables in laravel with foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Medical Table

[image]

Patient Table

[image]

Medical Model

```
public function patients() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
        }
```

Patient Model

```
public function medicals() {
            return $this->hasMany(Medical::class) ;
            }
```

MedicalController

```
 public function index()
    {
    
        $medicals=Medical::all();
        return view('main.medicalrecord.index',compact('medicals'));
    }
```

medicalrecord.index VIEW

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><strong>Patient No.</strong></th>//from the Patient table
            <th><strong>First Name</strong></th>//from the Patient table
            <th><strong>Middle Name</strong></th>//from the Patient table
            <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th>//from the Patient table
            <th><strong>Smoke</strong></th>//from the Medical table
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @if($medicals)
            @foreach($medicals as $medical)
          <tr>
          <td>{{$medical->patient_id}}</td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
            @endforeach
         @endif
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Hi Guys, I'm using foreign key which is $table->foreign('patient_id')->references('id')->on('patients'); in the medical migration.

How to get the data of Patient DB which is id,firstname,middlename,lastname and fetch to the Medical Table in my View in short how to join two table which is Patient table and Medical Table with the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Medical model

```
public function patient() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
}
```

You can access the patient's data using `patient` relation from medical instance like this.

In your view

```
        @if($medicals)
            @foreach($medicals as $medical)
          <tr>
          <td>{{$medical->patient->id}}</td>
          <td>{{$medical->patient->firstname}}</td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
            @endforeach
         @endif
```

Also, it's better if you eager load the patient relation in the controller.

```
$medicals=Medical::with('patient')->get();
```

Comment: where do I put him in the Controller or View?

Comment: You can access it like this in the controller as well as the view.

Comment: Sir is it okay to you to give the examples how to apply in my table I'm still learning in laravel.

Comment: I saw your post and you were trying to access it in view, but it's same for the view and controller. So earlier I wrote in a general manner. But I've added the example in the post. Hope it helps :)